# Quickly lookup MSDN documentation

Tags: visual-studio

I often need to look up documentation about classes/methods in the CLR. My usual process is just typing the method/class name into Google. But I would like to be able to right click any method within Visual Studio, and then click "Lookup on MSDN". Is there something already built in for this that I'm missing?

For example, I want to right click "Directory" in `System.IO.Directory` and then be taken [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Directory.aspx).

I am on Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the library locally - this is something that is offered during the Visual Studio installation process.

Re-run the installer and you should be presented with the option to install some of the articles locally (you can choose which items you want).

Comment: See this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/73123770-b8d9-425f-96b1-90c1983bf133/where-can-i-down-download-msdn-library-2010-for-free

Comment: Ah, figured it out. After doing what was mentioned in the forums you linked to, pressing F1 over a keyword will look it up.